# Can't Import From Excel into SSIS on Server

Tags: excel, ssis, oledb

I'm using VS2008 on W2k8 R2 with 64-bit office 2010 installed.

I created an SSIS project on my workstation and ran in 32-bit mode (as I got this error) in VS. It works perfectly here. Because I'm using bulk insert, I need to move the project to the server to complete the dev (it will ultimately run in SQL on this server). When I try to run in VS on server, I get this again

The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered.

The SSIS project is set for 32-bit mode (tryied 64-bit too). I've run AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe in admin shell with /passive option and still no luck.  I can't change the xlsx file as it's an auto-download and has to be a fully automated import and it won;t let me install 32bit access DBEngine.

Any suggestions

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue a while back and ended up installing the 32 bit version of AccessDatabaseEngine.exe. Depending on the server configuration certain ways of executing a package will force it into a 32 or 64 bit mode. If running from BIDS I believe it defaults to 32 bit mode. I believe the same is true for dtexec (non UI). You could also try running it from a SQL Server Agent Job, which would execute as 64 bit mode.

Comment: I downloaded the Office 2010 x86 version that was with the x64 version and it refused to install; however, this version (from office 2007) worked: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734